# react navigation unwanted render

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

i'm using bottom tab bar and one tab has a badge. it's a basket and bagde show the how many product in it. when i update the basket qty with redux it renders all navigation. how do i prevent it ?

this is the tab

```
<Tab.Screen
            name="BasketStack"
            component={BasketStack}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: () =>
                  <View>
                    <Badge
                      value={props.counter}
                      status="error"
                      containerStyle={{position: 'absolute', top: -5, left: 20}}
                    />
                    <Icon
                      size={24}
                      color="#222"
                      type="antdesign"
                      name={'shoppingcart'}
                    />
                  </View>
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Why does the re-render bother you?

Comment: @RajendranNadar it re-render the entire navigation. when user in product detail and add something to the basket, it re-renders all and go back to product list. i want to re-render only badge part

Comment: Your redux provider will be in the root, so the changes will update the entire tree as they are the children

Comment: @RajendranNadar i solved it, that problem happens because of badge is in navigation file also. i seperated it in another file. it works just like i want it

Comment: That is great..! 